# ExecuteAsync failing but Execute works fine

Tags: c#, async-await, restsharp

I am automating web services using [restsharp](/questions/tagged/restsharp) as below

```
public async Task<IRestClient> GetAuthorizedRequestClient(string baseUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            string authorizeUrl = await GetAuthorizationURL(baseUrl);
            //Some code here
            return authorizedClient;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    async Task<string> GetAuthorizationURL(string baseUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new RestClient(baseUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest("Home", Method.GET);
            var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);                
            return response.Headers.First(p => p.Name == "Location").Value.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

It is failing at `client.ExecuteAsync(request);` without throwing any exception i.e. execution gets terminated. When I use Execute instead of ExecuteAsync, it works fine and returns a response. Is it a issue of [restsharp](/questions/tagged/restsharp) or [async-await](/questions/tagged/async-await) code? Answering it in detail will help a lot, as I am new to [restsharp](/questions/tagged/restsharp) as well as async programming.

Comment: Since you are new to all of this, you should just cut to the chase and use `HttpClient`. RestSharp, WebRequest et al. are antiquated and considered legacy.

Comment: The first thing to check for is that the calling code is using `await`.